# How to correctly use Dagger 2's field injection with LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, libgdx, dagger-2

I have a problem with injecting some dependencies in my LibGDX-based game.
Can anyone point me what I am missing?

I have two modules.

First provides Android's `Context`:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    Context context;

    public AppModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context providesContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

Second provides class that interacts with Google Analytics:

```
@Module
public class ServicesModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    AnalyticsUtils providesAnalyticsUtils(Context context) {
        return new AnalyticsUtils(context);
    }
}
```

My component class is implemented this way:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, ServicesModule.class})
public interface GameComponent {
    void inject(Launcher launcher);
}
```

Now, I have added custom Application class (defined in manifest) where I have instantiated my component:

```
public class GameApplication extends Application {
    private GameComponent gameComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        gameComponent = DaggerGameComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .servicesModule(new ServicesModule())
            .build();
    }

    public GameComponent getGameComponent() {
        return gameComponent;
    }
}
```

In LibGDX Android's launcher, in `onCreate` method I am calling component's `inject()` method:

```
public class Launcher extends AndroidApplication {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ((GameApplication) getApplication()).getGameComponent().inject(this);

        initialize(new GameName());
    }
}
```

Let's say `GameName` is a class that extends LibGDX's `Game` class. In it's `create` method I am calling `setScreen` method that starts my menu screen.

My `MenuScreen` class:

```
public class MenuScreen extends ScreenAdapter {
    @Inject AnalyticsUtils analyticsUtils;

    public MenuScreen(GameName game) {
        // Some initialization.
        useAnalytics();
    }

    private void useAnalytics() {
        analyticsUtils.someMethod();
    }
}
```

As presented above, in `MenuScreen` class I want to inject `AnalyticsUtils` class using field injection.

In constructor I am calling a method that uses `analyticsUtils` object and calls it's method.

At the line, where I am calling `analyticsUtils.someMethod()` I am getting and `NullPointerExcetion` (trying to call `.someMethod()` on a `null` object).

Should I use component's `inject()` method in every single class in which I am injecting anything (no matter using field / constructor injection)?

I have read a lot of Dagger's tutorials and docs, but every of available examples are simple (mostly, they show simple injections in activities).

After few hours of trying I have decided I need to ask someone who is more experienced in Dagger. I will be glad for any hints and / or resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An annotation by itself will not do anything—`MenuScreen` is nowhere supplied with its dependency.

**Use constructor injection whenever possbile.**

Field injection is to be used by activities and fragments, since you can not modify/use their constructor. Besides some rare cases, you should use constructor injection whenever possible.

```
public class MenuScreen extends ScreenAdapter {
    private final AnalyticsUtils analyticsUtils;

    @Inject 
    public MenuScreen(GameName game, AnalyticsUtils analyticsUtils) {
        this.analyticsUtils = analyticsUtils;
        // Some initialization.
        useAnalytics();
    }

    private void useAnalytics() {
        analyticsUtils.someMethod();
    }
}
```

This will work if all dependencies can be supplied.

**Using dagger means you should *not* call construcors yourself**

```
((GameApplication) getApplication()).getGameComponent().inject(this);

initialize(new GameName());
```

`GameName` should *obviously* be provided from `GameComponent`.

**Don't use modules if you can just provide classes**

```
@Provides
@Singleton
AnalyticsUtils providesAnalyticsUtils(Context context) {
    return new AnalyticsUtils(context);
}
```

You don't need any of this. Annotate `class AnalyticsUtils` with `@Singleton` and its constructor with `@Inject`, and it can be provided. *Without* any module. This is what constructor injection is.

**Use inject**

You do not provide much context about what you are doing where. But given that `GameName` can be provided, `MenuScreen` can be constructed. You could e.g. just do the following

```
@Inject
GameName mGame;
@Inject
MenuScreen mMenu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ((GameApplication) getApplication()).getGameComponent().inject(this);

    initialize(mGame);
}
```

Comment: In fact, my `MenuScreen` class (and many others) uses much more dependencies which I wanted to inject.

As I suppose I should create such terrible constructor with multiple arguments or create wrapper class containing other objects? This is the reason why I wanted to use field injection.

Comment: @tommus I would consider "Wrapper classes containing other objects" also as an anti pattern. if you have too many dependencies for a single class this will probably mean that it is doing too much. You then should extract some of its features to other classes

Comment: Yes, I have tought about that a moment after posting my comment. Moreover - thanks for Your responses. I marked Your answer as correct. It shed some light on the topic and changed my point of view and understanding of Dagger (especially shortcut that relies on the lack of a requirements to use modules).